# PowerShell Exchange disable OWA from OU sort

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

I am searching a specific OU, then disabling OWA for all users in the OU.  This script runs daily.

I have the following script that works properly but is updating ALL the users in the OU.

```
$OU='OU=SomeOU,DC=Domain,DC=com'
$ext14='00254'
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU| Where {$_.CustomAttribute14 -eq $ext14} | Set-CASMailbox -OWAEnabled:$false
```

I would like to ONLY update users that -OWAEnabled is set to `$True` (and change to $false) in this OU and sub OUs.  This would reduce my calls to Exchange.
Unfortunately, `Set-CASMailbox` does not seem to have an `OU` or `CustomAttribute`  property to query against.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CASMailbox object does not have the OU or CustomAttribute properties, but the Mailbox object does have protocolsettings property collection, so:

```
$OU='OU=SomeOU,DC=Domain,DC=com'
$ext14='00254'
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU|
Where {($_.CustomAttribute14 -eq $ext14) -and ($_.protocolsettings -match 'OWA.1'} |
Set-CASMailbox -OWAEnabled:$false
```

Comment: i wonder if there is a similar one for -MAPIBlockOutlookRpcHttp?

Comment: Yes, found it.  MAPI.0  Excellent!!

Comment: Probably.  I don't know where you'd find the docs on how that's stored in those protocolsetting strings, but I'd wager with a little experimenting you could figure it out and write the regex you need to match it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-CASMailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU | ? {
  $_.CustomAttribute14 -eq $ext14 -and $_.OWAEnabled
} | % {
  Set-CASMailbox -Identity $_.Identity -OWAEnabled:$false
}
```